# I used the'-print0' option to handle filenames with spaces, but I get an error

Tags: bash, shell, find, rename, mv

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/data -name '*QQ*' -print0 -exec bash -c ' mv $1 ${0/\-QQ/-TT}' {} \;
```

I used the'-print0' option to handle filenames with spaces, but I get an error

```
/home/data/gone to sea.1080p-QQ.mp4mv: target 'sea.1080p-TT.mp4' is not a directory
```

Which part is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This might help: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: The `-print0` option isn't really accomplishing anything here; it literally just prints the filenames with null bytes afterward. It has no impact on `-exec`.

Comment: You can only use `-print0` when you're piping to a program that's designed to parse null-separated filenames, such as `xargs -0`.

Comment: I was missing something important. Thank you. I'm learning something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `-print0`, since you're not piping the output to another program.

You just need to quote properly in the bash command.

```
find /home/data -name '*-QQ*' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/\-QQ/-TT}"' {} {} \;
```

This should work as long as the filenames don't contain double quote or `$` characters.

You could also avoid `bash -c` by using the `rename` command:

```
find /home/data -name '*-QQ*' -exec rename 's/-QQ/-TT/' {} +
```

Comment: @ruakh `bash -c` is needed to use the `${1/-QQ/-TT}` substitution

Comment: Of course, another solution is to use the `rename` command.